# Get contents size of text widget in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, text, widget, dimensions

Is there a way I can get the dimensions of the contents of a Tk.Text widget. For example with a canvas I can do `canvas.bbox('all')` to give me the dimensions of the contents. This is crucial to my program so how is this possible with a text widget?

I want to be able to disable a scrollbar when there is not enough contents for the scrollbar to be active.

```
import tkinter as tk

def getDims():
   print('How do I print the dimensions of the text box here')

root=tk.Tk()

text=tk.Text(root)
text.pack(fill='both')

var='How can I find the dimensions of this text inside the tkinter textbox widget in pixels ?'
text.insert('end',var)

b=tk.Button(root,text='Get Dimensions!',command=getDims)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `count` method to get the number of pixels between the first and last characters. This method takes two indexes, and then one or more strings representing what you want to count: chars, displaychars, displayindices, displaylines, indices, lines, xpixels, or ypixels. The return value is a tuple containing the count of each requested item.

For example, to count the pixels from the top of the first character to the bottom of the last character you could do this:

```
ypixels = text.count("1.0", "end", "ypixels")[0]
```

Another way to determine if you should show the scrollbar is to call the `yview` method. If it returns `(0.0, 1.0)`, that tells you that the entire text is visible. If any portion is scrolled off of the screen, that function will return something different.

Comment: Hi Bryan, after working with your solution for a while, the bottom paragraph. I managed to get this solution working for a Text widget however using the same method with a scrollable canvas the ```yview``` method is returning ```(0.0,1.0)``` every time even if the contents is off the screen? Why is this?

Comment: @MaksOvnik: probably because you haven't configured the `scrollregion` attribute of the canvas.

Comment: You're right, although I had configured the scrollregion attribute of the canvas with an update method I wasn't calling the method when adding elements to the canvas. ```<Configure>``` does not catch this event. Many thanks